# Getting results when not inside row of the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having some difficulties while trying to find out the query that I need at the moment.

I'll try to explain the situation the best I can and keep it as short as possible.

I have a many-to-many table called articles_properties, which comes out from the combination of two other tables: articles and properties. These tables have the following structures, with the most important columns and also with some examples:

```
Property table
-------------------------
|  id   |  property_name|
|   1   |      name     |
|   2   |   variations  |
-------------------------

Article table
--------------
|     id     |
|     A1     |
|     A2     |
|     A3     |
|     A4     |
|     A5     |
--------------

Article_properties table
--------------------------------------------------
| article_id  |  property_id  |  property_value  |
|     A1      |       1       |      Pencil      |
|     A1      |       2       |      A2, A3      |
|     A2      |       1       |   Pencil (blue)  |
|     A3      |       1       |   Pencil (green) |
|     A4      |       1       |       Book       |
|     A5      |       1       |    Tennis ball   |
--------------------------------------------------
```

It is basically what you can see. Maybe the only one that doesn't seem intuitive is variations: it is a property to determine the different variations of an article. For instance the article Pencil has two variations: Pencil (blue) and Pencil (green), indicated with their respective article id inside the column property_value.

Now the problem is that I would like to get from the Article_properties table all the articles except the ones that appear inside the property variation of another one. This means I would like to get a result like the following one:

```
Query result
--------------------------------------------------
| article_id  |  property_id  |  property_value  |
|     A1      |       1       |      Pencil      |
|     A1      |       2       |      A2, A3      |
|     A4      |       1       |       Book       |
|     A5      |       1       |    Tennis ball   |
--------------------------------------------------
```

How can I do it while keeping it as simple and clean as possible? At the moment I have the following query, which doesn't work as expected:

```
SELECT ap.* FROM article_properties ap 
LEFT JOIN property p ON p.id = ap.property_id 
WHERE (p.property_name = 'name' OR p.property_name = 'variations') 
AND ap.property_value != '' 
AND  ap.property_value NOT LIKE CONCAT('%',ap.article_id,'%') 
GROUP BY ap.article_id, ap.property_id
```

What is exactly my mistake or what am I missing?

Thank you for taking your time answering.

Comment: Your first problem is (an apparent) lack of normalization

Comment: What has the `Article` table got to do with anything here?

Comment: You might consider having a table of 'variations' 'A2, A3' is not a valid variation.

Comment: Yes, both of you are right: the database is pretty old and wrongly made at that time, that is why it has such an ugly structure to start with. However I am not allowed to change it, which is a burden when trying to make any query, even the simpliest ones..

Comment: Luckily, that's not our problem :-) There's simply no point proceeding with the present structure.

Answer (score 1):

I aint working much with MySQL .. but problem seems fun so I tried to solve it using T-SQL ... and this is how i would do it in T-SQL ... if you can translate it into MySQL, hopefully it will do you good.

Anyway this is what i did

Just setting up data here, to be kinda the same as your input

```
If object_id('tempdb..#temp') is not null drop table #temp
create table #Temp (ID int, descriptions nvarchar(100))
insert into #Temp (ID, descriptions) values (2, 'A2, A3'),
(1, 'Pencil (blue)'),
(1, 'Pencil (green)'),
(1, 'Book'),
(1, 'Tennis ball'),
(1, 'Pencil')
```

Creating tempTables, with row_number just for a while loop and ordering by 'descriptions desc' .. that way 'Pencil (green)' goes before 'Pencil'

```
If object_id('tempdb..#tempWithRowNum') is not null drop table #tempWithRowNum
    select row_number() over (order by descriptions desc) rownum, 
  * into #tempWithRowNum from #temp t1

If object_id('tempdb..#Finish') is not null drop table #Finish
create table #Finish (LastStanding_property nvarchar(100))
```

Getting Max for while loop and setting variables

```
declare @s int = (select max(rownum) from (
    select row_number() over (order by descriptions desc) rownum, 
 * from #temp t1) 
src)

declare @Thing nvarchar(100)
declare @cmd nvarchar(max)
declare @Count int
declare @ParmDefinition nvarchar(100)
declare @i int = 1
```

Here is logic ... I am just running through whole table using one description, and if I get count(*) higher then 1, which means you have some property_value similar

```
while @i <= @s 
    begin

    set @Thing = (select descriptions from #tempWithRowNum where rownum = @i)

    set @cmd = 'select @retvalOut = count(*) 
                  from #temp where descriptions like ''%'  + @Thing + '%'''


    SET @ParmDefinition = N'@retvalOUT int OUTPUT';

    EXEC sp_executesql @cmd, @ParmDefinition, @retvalOUT=@Count OUTPUT;

    IF @Count = 1 
    begin
      insert into #Finish (LastStanding_property) values (@Thing)
    end
    else
    begin   
       set @cmd = 'delete from #Finish where LastStanding_property like ''%' + @Thing + '%'''
       execute (@cmd)
       insert into #Finish (LastStanding_property) values (@Thing)
    end

    set @i = @i + 1
end

select * from #Finish
```

So, like I said .. If you get Count(*) higher then 1 ... means you have "Child" property value ... you delete them from #Finish table and insert "parent" value and you get what you want